# Pdf reader for iOS with scrollView

Tags: ios, arrays, pdf, uiscrollview

I use `CGContextDrawPDFPage` for drawing my pdf. I have a `scrollView` and 2 arrays with low and high resolution images. When user scrolling on `scrollView` load low resolution images, after method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` it load high resolution image for this page.

I use `removeFromSuperView` for low resolution image and add high but my scroll is blinking.

How can I delete low image without blinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you are worried about performance on scrolling , I will suggest using titled layer rendering. Apple [ZoominPdfViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) should be the best example.

Comment: I use it, but in example it high resolution image at all. But my problem is that if i didn't delete low resolution image and add high resolution image when zooming i can see at some borders low resolution image. So i need to remove it and add high but, when i make it my scroll is blinking

Comment: Sorry, I really cant understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have 2 methods, onу for load low resolution images, second for load high resolution images. when user scrolling on `didscroll` i use first method. when he stop i use secoтd so the problem is that i need to delete low from superView and add hidh resolution image on scrollView, but wneh i make this my scrollView is blinking

Comment: In what order you are doing this. you should add then remove.